# perl cgi shows plain text in https only?

Tags: apache, cgi

I have an odd issue with my webserver (redhat/apache).  There are two sites on the server, each with their own virtualhost section in httpd-vhosts.conf and ssl.conf.

One site is primarily perl/cgi and works fine.  I am able to properly execute perl/cgi scripts in the root folder as well as cgi-bin and subfolders of both areas.  I can access the cgi files from http and https URLs.

If I try to put a cgi file in my other site it will execute if I access it via http but not if I access it via https.  (it only displays the code as plain text if I use https)

As far as I can tell both sites are configured identically in both .conf files.

Any idea why it might be doing this?

Comment: My first check would be the configuration for the HTTPS virtual server. Is it set up to serve cgi scripts?

Comment: The specific virtualhost entry for it is configured identically on the 443 and 80 versions, the 443 just has the 3 additional lines for SSL.  One thing I did find is that the '<VirtualHost _default_:443>' has the same url, maybe that is overriding the other one somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down the issue.  There was an entry in ssl.conf for '' and it had the same url as the site that wasnt working.  That one was apparently overriding the one farther down which had the correct cgi config.